# Is there a way to preload a WKWebView in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, wkwebview

I'm building a demo application that is a combo of HTML and Javascript and real iOS controls.  The HTML content will ship within the application bundle.

I'm overlaying invisible buttons on the WKWebView to activate real functions in the app. In order to position them properly, I'd like to have the WKWebView load its first page in Interface Builder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it programatically, in view will appear of the view controller class attached to the nib file. You cannot do it directly in Interface Builder.